# Nodejs pug extend

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

Absolute beginner here. I just setup new server using node.js but stuck on the pug views. Trying to extends login.pug into index.pug but all i get is blank content except the footer and head. Where did i do wrong? Help please...
p/s: pug already installed

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

// for parsing application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// for parsing application/xwww-
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
//form-urlencoded

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});

// for parsing multipart/form-data
app.use(upload.array());
app.use(express.static('public'));
```

```html
//index.pug

doctype html
html(lang="en")
head
    meta( charset="utf-8")
    meta( name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1")
    title COMPANY WEBAPP
    meta( name="description" content="MKE Web App.")
    meta( name="keywords" content="MKE Web App.")
    link( rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="img/icon/favicon.png")
    link( rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css")
    link( rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css")

    body
        block content

        footer
            p( id="copyright") Copyright &copy; 2019
            p( id="visitcount") Loading...

        script( type="text/javascript" src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
        script( type="text/javascript" src="js/hmac-sha3.js")
        script( type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js")


//login.pug
extends index

block content
    div(class="login-continer")
        form( class="form-login default-box" method="POST" action="/login")
            div
                label( for="user-id") <strong>User ID :</strong>
                span( class="span-login-symbol")  &#128113;
                input( class="default-input" id="user-id" type="test" placeholder="user id" value="" spellcheck="false" required)
            div
                label( for="user-email") <strong>Email :</strong>
                span( class="span-login-symbol") &#128140;
                input( class="default-input" id="user-email" type="email" placeholder="user email" value="" spellcheck="false" required)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index');
});
```

You are rendering index.pub on get. However, you have not extended **login.pub** into your index. You are instead extending index into your **login.pub**

If you just change the render to login, you should be able to see the new content.

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});
```